# Spring boot/Spring MVC - How to forward a response from another request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I need a rest end point whose response is HTML. But instead of a view defined in my project, i would like to forward the HTML response from another request made inside that rest end point. 
For example, my rest end point makes a http request to an internal service and returns the HTML returned from that service? Is it possible? Any thoughts?
Here is a code example

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String testMe(Model model, @RequestParam("param1") String param1, @RequestParam("param2") String param2)
{
    //Make a Http call to an internal service and return the response from that call
    return "<RESPONSE_FROM_THAT_CALL>";
}
```

I would like to return the HTML response from the internal service

Comment: So your question is how to return a string?

Comment: If i return a string, spring assumes its a name of a view and errors out. I want to return HTML as part of the response

Comment: An HTML document is a string, isn't it? If a method is annotated with `@ResponseBody` then Spring returns the string, not a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `RestTemplate` to fetch the result from the other service and just return it as a `String`:

```java
@Controller
public class MyController {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String testMe(Model model, @RequestParam("param1") String param1, @RequestParam("param2") String param2) {
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://www.example.com");
            .queryParam("param1", param1)
            .queryParam("param2", param2)
            .build()
            .toUri());
        return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    }
}
```

If you'll have more endpoints that you wanna proxy to another service, you should consider using e.g. Zuul as a micro proxy. See e.g. [this blog post](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/) explaining how you can easily create such a proxy.